# Check if a char is a quotation mark

Tags: c#

I need to check if the first character is a quotation mark (`"`).

```
if (!arrayDataSet[i][0].Equals("\"")) {
  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(arrayDataSet[i][0].ToString());
  stringBuilder.Append("\"" + arrayDataSet[i]);
  stringBuilder.Append(',');
}
```

Problem is that it continues into the if statement even if the first character is a `"`. My `MessageBox` even prints a `"` when printing it.

Comment: What is `arrayDataSet`?

Comment: did you try `if (!arrayDataSet[i][0].Equals('\"'))`?

Answer (score 2):

The char `'a'` is not the same as the string `"a"`. `'a'.Equals("a")` will return `false`.

You want to test whether the first character is equal to the character `'"'`. The easiest way to do this is:

```
if (arrayDataSet[i][0] != '"')
```

Alternative, you can do:

```
if (!arrayDataSet[i].StartsWith("\""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try linq as well,

```
if (arrayDataSet[i].FirstOrDefault() != '"')
{
  //Your logic
}
```